# Change iPhone pin remotely

Tags: iphone

iPhone SE without Touch ID.

my problem is that a specific area on the screen is not working. Hence I am unable to unlock the phone using a pin number.

So, is there any way I can unlock the iPhone remotely? Using iCloud or iTunes?

Answer (score 14):

[Source](https://deciphertools.com/blog/iphone-passcode-broken-screen/):

No, you can't unlock the iPhone remotely.  You can use VoiceOver to select the numbers on the screen.

1. Hold down the Home button to activate Siri. Say “Turn on VoiceOver”.
2. Press the Home button twice to bring up the passcode screen.
3. Use the portion of your screen that responds to touch to swipe left and right, which will move your VoiceOver cursor to different passcode number buttons. VoiceOver will also say the button being selected, which is helpful if you can't see the screen.
4. When the cursor is on the passcode number you need, double tap the screen to “tap” the selected passcode number.
5. After the iPhone unlocks, you may need VoiceOver one last time to tap “Trust” in the dialog that comes up when you plug in your iPhone to your computer.
6. Copy your photos and/or make your backup in iTunes.

To turn off VoiceOver, you can say “Turn off VoiceOver” to Siri, or go into `Settings -> General -> Accessibility` to turn it off manually.

Comment: Cool! I learn something new every day on this site.

Comment: If you have a Mac, you can use QuickTime in addition to this to see the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is connected to your company’s system using Microsoft Intune, there is a feature in the Company Portal that does allow you to remotely reset your password. Other Mobile Device Management platforms may have the feature too.

I needed to do this recently and it worked. Only caveat was that FaceID/Touch ID needed to be reconfigured. A couple other key chain things needed to be reset too, but I got access to all of my data, photos, etc.